# Перевод кода с языка пайтон на js

Tags: javascript, python

```
matrix = [
    [2.1,4.3,5.4,1.4,-1.4],
    [2.1,3.2,4.1,5.1,3.2],
    [0.0,1.0,5.1,4.3,7.2],
    [5.1,6.2,4.2,3.1,4.3],
    [7.1,8.2,4.1,3.3,4.2]
]
 

n = 5

a = []
for i in range(n):
    row_abs = [abs(matrix[i][j]) for j in range(n)]
    a.append(sum(row_abs))
print(f'A = {max(a)}')
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код на JavaScript и почему он не работает.

Comment: Вы комментарии к каждой строке кода напишите и тогда все будет ясно. Или хотя бы что выводит в итоге ваш код? Максимальную сумму абсолютных величин значений подмассивов? Или что?

Comment: Этот код ищет l-норму указаной матрицы по формуле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
let matrix = [
    [2.1,4.3,5.4,1.4,-1.4],
    [2.1,3.2,4.1,5.1,3.2],
    [0.0,1.0,5.1,4.3,7.2],
    [5.1,6.2,4.2,3.1,4.3],
    [7.1,8.2,4.1,3.3,4.2]
];

console.log(`A = ${Math.max(...matrix.map(arr => arr.reduce((acc,item) => Math.abs(item) + acc, 0)))}`);
```